# Edge bevel only affects one face

Tags: bevel

I am trying to bevel this edge:

[image]

When I do so, the bevel only affects the vertical face.  The horizontal face is impervious:

[image]

I have done all the normal things like checking normals, applying scaling, etc.  I have done what I can to remove bad geometry. There are no duplicates for example.

What have I done??

blend file: [image]

ANSWER:

Thanks to Lemon and Gordon Brinkman I see that the bevel I want cannot be created because the larger horizontal surface (in this case) isn't bounded by an edge.

Here's what happens if I try after select not just the original edge, but the ones all the way around.  Suddenly, Bevel is working. Now this result is awful but that isn't the point.

[image]

Comment: I think this is a normal behaviour, as the bevel you want should involve more than one edge.

Comment: What kind of result do you expect here?

Comment: a 45 degree bevel on the edge highlighted, including both adjacent faces.

Comment: without any impact on the vertical bevels on both sides? (I'm still unable to vizualize what you want...)

Comment: @lemon see the edge that's highlighted in the first pic? Use Bevel to turn it into a face that is 45 degrees with respect to the adjacent large horizontal face, and large vertical face.

Comment: I think the best you can expect is something like that https://i.stack.imgur.com/66Ghg.png is it what you want?

Comment: @TonyEnnis I would like you to visualize how you want the bevel to be realized without affecting the adjacent faces.

Comment: or that ? https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ijc0H.png

Comment: @TonyEnnis By the way, you see that the bevel segments run down the bordering vertical edges? That's why it's not affecting the top horizontal face: there are no edges in the direction the bevel would move along.

Comment: @lemon if the Bevel command did *anything* I'd be happier.  Those results aren't what I am looking for, but I am unable to get it to do anything at all.

Comment: So then my issue is really the lack of an edge that's heavily implied by @lemon's 2nd image.